# Is there a standard thread safe nomenclature?

Tags: multithreading

Is there a standard terminology that distinguishes between objects that are safe to use in a multi-threaded environment with locking (my object has no unprotected static members) and objects that are safe to use concurrently in a MT environment (maybe because I put locks around all the public methods)?

Let me add a little more explanation: I have a C++ library that is overall safe to use in a multithreaded environment but is not thread safe. The library contains an exception class inherited from std::exception. The what() method returns a char*. Since I'm stuck with the signature defined in the parent, I have to return memory internal to the class rendering this particular method even more unsafe than the rest of the library. I'm looking for some standard terminology to use when documenting this method.

Comment: You mean, other than "thread-safe"?

Comment: Yes, because I want to distinguish between safe in an MT environment and safe to use concurrently.

Comment: What is the difference between using an object concurrently and using the object on multiple threads?

Comment: For objects containing a static member not protected by a lock, it's not safe to access different instances of an object from different threads. For objects that are safe in an MT-environment, like STL containers, it's OK as long as you don't access the same instance of an object concurrently.

Comment: Well, neither type is thread-safe, but the former is even less safe than usual because its instances depend on non-safe statics.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I understand the distinction you're making.  However, if a single object cannot be safely used in different threads concurrently, it's usually not considered thread-safe.  Most people don't bother to distinguish between different degrees of non-thread-safe code. :)

Comment: @Kirk: The de facto default is that statics are thread-safe, instances are not. So, for example, you could use an instance in a single thread without a problem, or use it across threads if you lock appropriately. A class that allows only a single instance across all threads is, well, toxic.

Answer (score 1):

Five years later I notice that the current Wikipeida article on thread safety lists three levels of thread safety:

*Thread safe*: Implementation is guaranteed to be free of race conditions when accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.

*Conditionally safe*: Different threads can access different objects simultaneously, and access to shared data is protected from race conditions.

*Not thread safe*: Code should not be accessed simultaneously by different threads.

The answer I was looking for was the "Conditionally Safe" category.

Answer (score -1):

Static methods that can be used in a multi-threaded environment are called "thread safe".

Instance objects that can be used by multiple threads simultaniously are usually called "immutable", since that is the most common mechanism for ensuring thread safety.

If you define "thread safe" in a broad sense to encompass not only the avoidance of data corruption but also the impossibility of a deadlock, then a mutable instance can rarely be made thread safe, since thread safety ultimately depends on how the object is used.

If you define "thread safe" narrowly to mean that the object is always left in a consistant state, then I don't know of any special terminology for such a thing.

It's usually better to define "thread safe" as a property of a whole system rather than an class.

Comment: Does this mean that you would define the STL containers to be "immutable" but not thread safe?

Comment: Immutability does lead to thread safety, but thread safety can be from other mechanisms than immutability. Therefore, I find this confusing and misleading.

Comment: Also, it's not at all hard to make a mutable object thread-safe without deadlocks.

Comment: @John Gordon - The STL containers are not immutable, and I would say that they are not at all thread safe.

Comment: @Steven Sudit - My point is that focusing on protecting the internals of an object rather than how the object is used is not a good approach to creating a multi-threaded program. It often leads to the appearance of safety but not the actual fact. For example, a "thread-safe" container object cannot have a Count property, because such a property would be utterly useless.

Comment: @Jeff: With all due respect, that's simply not the case. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287234.aspx.  The `Count` is necessarily subject to a safe race condition, in that it can only tell you what the count was at the moment you called, not what it will be a moment later. But then again, that's always true.

Comment: @Jeff: STL containers are indeed *not* thread-safe. However, they're also not toxic, so nothing stops you from, for example, having a `vector<int>` instance in one thread, and another such instance in a different thread. If they have any statics that they care about, those are properly locked.

Comment: @Steven Sudit - OK, I see what you are saying. I hadn't considered the case where two objects of the same class cannot be used in separate threads. I would call such a thing "crazy"!

Comment: It may be crazy, but it's really easy to do if you're not thinking about it. Almost any class with static data will be unsafe in an MT environment, if you're not thinking about it and don't add a static lock.

Comment: @John Gordon - That is one of several reasons why static data is the evil.

Comment: "Crazy", "toxic", "evil": they all fit.